# Should I include an edge case in code that will never run?

Tags: c

I heard that setting ones clock to a time close to or before January 1st 1970 can cause a device to brick itself. I suspect that it may be because `getCurrentTime() - startTime` is not the safest way to calculate time elapsed

```
uint64_t deltaTime(uint64_t current, uint64_t previous) { // Calculates delta time through overflows
    if (current >= previous) {
        return current - previous;
    }
    return ~(previous - current) + 1;
}
```

I have this code that calculates delta time. Given that the time in nanoseconds won't overflow for 292 years, the if statement will almost never return false. Would you still include the overflow case, even though it will only happen every 292 years or so? Also, if one has a code base already uses `getCurrentTime() - startTime` everywhere, should all of them be modified to the "safer" method of calculation?

Comment: "A device" meaning what, exactly?

Comment: Don't write code that expects to be running in 292 years, because I assure you it will absolutely not be. What will happen is corrupted input trips this code and you don't handle it properly. Remember, time will flutter a bit and this will not *always* be true, NTP sync can kick your system time around +/- a few seconds now and then, or a few minutes if it's drifted out of sync badly before a correction is applied.

Comment: Do you *completely trust* your source of the time reading? Can't it give a wrong value? What would be the consequences if it does? If it indeed "bricks" the device, it is better to have a graceful handling even if you believe it will never happen.

Comment: I use `int64_t` for time values. Works pretty well for benchmarks even with nanosecond resolution. And, I use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,...)` so NTP adjustments are less of a problem. Times before 1970 are okay, just negative. Note that `time` uses `long` and _not_ `unsigned long`

Comment: when compiling with at least `-O1` the if statement is optimized out: https://godbolt.org/z/bWah1evs1

Comment: Do you realize that both `return` expressions would always return exactly the same value as each other? If not, then you need to brush up on the rules of unsigned integer arithmetic in C.

Comment: I guess you never ran into the problem where the coin cell battery on the motherboard goes out after which the RTC goes bananas. Hardware can fail, software can fail, design rugged programs, not "theoretically correct" programs.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it does not require the `if` as `current - previous` does exactly the same as `~(previous - current) + 1` for `current < previous`

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint64_t deltaTime(uint64_t current, uint64_t previous) { // Calculates delta time through overflows
    if (current >= previous) {
        return current - previous;
    }
    return ~(previous - current) + 1;
}

uint64_t deltaTime1(uint64_t current, uint64_t previous) { // Calculates delta time through overflows
    return current - previous;
}


int main(void)
{
    printf("%"PRIu64" %"PRIu64"\n", deltaTime(1,5), deltaTime(5,1));
    printf("%"PRIu64" %"PRIu64"\n", deltaTime1(1,5), deltaTime1(5,1));

    printf("%"PRIu64" %"PRIu64"\n", deltaTime(5,5), deltaTime(0,0));
    printf("%"PRIu64" %"PRIu64"\n", deltaTime1(5,5), deltaTime1(0,0));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/o4M1jx7dK

So the question makes no sense - the `if` is not needed because both expressions do exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

> Should I include an edge case in code that will never run?

*never* is a long time.

The `if` serves no purpose as well explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78076627/2410359) answer and [Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78076369/should-i-include-an-edge-case-in-code-that-will-never-run/78079783#comment137643181_78076369).

Code is more likely to change than the machine will run 100s of years.

- Use `static_assert()` to test limits at compile time to help detect code update woes.

Consider *time* units are later updated from *nanoseconds* to *picoseconds*.  Then `current >= previous` may occur in 0.292 years.

In that case, samples for time will wrap-around every 0.292 years.  Yet if code samples are less than 0.292 years apart, the *difference* will remain in `uint64_t` range with a simple subtraction even if the original time samples wrap.

---

I'd recommend to leave `getCurrentTime() - startTime` (not use `deltaTime()`) in your code with a `static_assert()` near `getCurrentTime()` concerning the truthfulness about the 292 year calculation at compile time.

```
#define TIME_OVERFLOW_YEAR 292
#define SECS_PER_YEAR (365.2425 * 24 * 60 * 60)
#define TIME_LIMIT_FP ((UINT64_MAX/2 + 1) * 2.0)
static_assert(TIME_LIMIT_FP/SECS_PER_YEAR/frequency > TIME_OVERFLOW_YEAR, 
    "Frequency too high");
```

BTW: I think OP's 292 year calculation is off by a factor of 2 for `uint64_t`.  I get 584 years.

---

On a more code-for-hire issue.

Good coding contract specify something like "code shall suffer no [Y2K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem) like issues from contract date + 100 years".

Put in your code these contract specs and test them.

```
#define TIMER_YEAR_EPOCH 2000
#define CONTRACT_YEAR 2024 // Contract #1.
#define TIME_OVERFLOW_YEAR (CONTRACT_YEAR - TIMER_YEAR_EPOCH + 100 + 1) // Contract #123.
```